# not able to assign data in webview when pushed from a table view to a view containing tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm parsing a json object and populating it in table view.

When the table view row is selected it navigates to a detailed view controller named as "ThirdDetailView" and was able to assign the parsed data in my ThirdDetailView (using web view).

Problem arises when my ThirdDetailView is one of  the view in my four tab bars .I have placed those four tabbar in a view called firstView, So that clicking on the tableview navigates to firstView containing four tabbars showing the ThirdDetailView as highlighted as the first tab.if this is the case data is not getting loaded in the web view.

**below is the code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     title=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSDictionary *detaildesc1=[media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  ThirdDetailView *detailViewController1= [[ThirdDetailView alloc]init];
    [detailViewController1 initWithItem:detaildesc1 Title:title];

     FirstView *dvController4 = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController4 animated:YES];

    [dvController4 release];

    [detailViewController1 release];
    }
    }
```

**ThirdDetailView**

```
@synthesize theItem1,theTitle,img,body,message,facebook,webview,id1;

     - (id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)detaildesc1 Title:(NSString *)title 
    {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"ThirdDetailView" bundle:nil]) {
    self.id1=detaildesc1;
    self.theTitle=title;
      urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark?parkid=%@",self.id1];
        baseURL =[[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]retain];
        jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];

        // self.title=title;

        NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

         boom=[items objectForKey:@"description"];
         NSLog(@"what is the text:%@",[items objectForKey:@"description"]);

         [self.webview loadHTMLString:boom baseURL:nil];
    }

return self;
    }
```

[image]

**FirstView Tabbar**
[image]

Comment: check the value self.id1 is nil or contain value. try with NSLog

Comment: the above is the string that i ve got in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Out this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"id1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"theTitle"];

     FirstView *dvController4 = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController4 animated:YES];

    [dvController4 release];

    [detailViewController1 release];
    }
    }


 - (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];
    id1 =    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id1"];
    theTitle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"theTitle"];
    NSLog(@"hi %@", id1);
    hello=@"hello";
    NSLog(@"ahhhha sdfgs :%@",theTitle);

    urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark?parkid=%@",self.id1];
    baseURL =[[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]retain];

    jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];

    NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    self.boom=[items objectForKey:@"description"];
    NSLog(@"retard:%@",self.boom);
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", self.boom];  
    [self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; 


}
```

I have tested in my app in perfectly show your text in webview

Comment: hey your coding of webview in THirdDetailView but you are not using

Comment: Third Detail View you are just allocate but do not use in FirstView

Comment: i ve edited my above answer..is dis the one you are mentioning

Comment: post your code of FirstView Controller. you need to use your Third View into FirstViewController

Comment: yup i post the code..there  aint much of code..everything is done in IBOutlet .i ll update the code

Comment: there is no code in FirstView.i used IBOutlet to setup my tabbarcontroller.if u want i could post u my screen shot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7515/discussion-between-cocoa-matters-and-kingston)

Comment: i ve attached a screen shot on how it looks firstview coz everything is done on IBOutlet.if u want i ll share with u my code

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have tried your code with the given URL 
`@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark?parkid=56"`
 and it's showing in my web view. 
Please check that your `IBOulet` is connected properly

---

**Edited**
hey you haven't used `detailViewController1` in `dvController4` in the above code..You have just allocated it and then released it but you haven't used it.This might be the bug.

Comment: der is no space in the code..its a mistake happened while copying in the stack

Comment: is your ` NSLog(@"what is the text:%@",[items objectForKey:@"description"]);` printing the text???

Comment: check my answer i ve attache the console output

Comment: i tried upadating your above string in webview still not getting updated

Comment: the above url works perfectly if i m going to navigate to ThirdViewDetail and my webview gets populated.The problem what i m facing is in my view Named "FirstView" i ve placed a tabbarcontroller containing four tabs and in my first tab i ve place thirdViewDetail.so its like i m passing my data to thirdViewDetail and navigate my stack to firstViewDetail...could u give a try using tabbar..any help is much appreciated

Comment: sorry i cant make a tab bar like you have made.. edited my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7513/discussion-between-inder-kumar-rathore-and-kingston)

Comment: i ve checked with your updated answer i m just values to another view